# Successful meditation between two countries requires patient and enthusiasm

Tags: grammaticality

> Successful meditation between two countries requires:
>
> A. Patient and enthusiasm
>   B. enthusiasm and patience
>   C. enthusiastic and patience

Which will be the right answer?

Comment: ***Patient*** and ***enthusiastic*** are ***adjectives***, but your example requires ***nouns*** (to refer to those ***things*** which are required). So what both you and your context need is ***patience*** and ***enthusiasm*** (abstract nouns). Alternatively, you could say that what they need ***to be*** is patient and enthusiastic.

Comment: ...and you mean _mediation_, not _meditation!_

Comment: Is this an exam question?

Answer (score 1):

your sentence needs nouns to get meaningful. like:
These pets requires a lot of **care** and **attention**. (care and attention are noun)

> Successful **mediation** between two countries requires **enthusiasm** and **patience**.

Answer (score 0):

"Require" requires a direct object, meaning it is a transitive verb. A direct object must be a noun, pronoun, or a phrase or clause acting as a complex noun.

"Patient" is an adjective, not a noun.

"Enthusiastic" is likewise an adjective rather than a noun.

Both "patience" and "enthusiasm" are nouns and so B is correct.

Comment: Thanks all for sensible reply.Yes it will be 'Mediation'